# finding corresponding data points in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data set contains a "score" containing floats and a "score phrase",a string describing the score. how do i use python/pandas to sort out and show me the score/scores that correspond to each Possible phrase?
below is the code i currently have to load the data from the excel file and filter it to just those two columns as well as put them in order of lowest to highest score.

```
reviews = pd.read_csv("ign.csv")

filter_reviews = reviews.loc[:,["score_phrase","score"]]

filtered_reviews = filter_reviews.sort_values(by =["score"])

print (filtered_reviews)
```

Comment: Its not clear what the data looks like and what output you want. Also indicate why your current code doesn't work as expected

Comment: the Data looks like this in the output of Spyder       
the current code works for its own function, i want to write a script that outputs all the possible scores that correspond with each phrase but im very new to python
score_phrase  score

5242      Disaster    0.5

890       Disaster    0.7

12513     Disaster    0.8

11362   Unbearable    1.0

1190    Unbearable    1.0
           ...    ...

1434   Masterpiece   10.0

1408   Masterpiece   10.0

1363   Masterpiece   10.0

8640   Masterpiece   10.0

18624  Masterpiece   10.0

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given the data in your comment, you can use groupby, nunique and to_list to get a list of all unique combinations.

```
df.groupby(["score_phrase", "score"]).nunique().index.to_list()

[('Disaster', 0.5), ('Disaster', 0.7), ('Disaster', 0.8), ('Masterpiece', 10.0), ('Unbearable', 1.0)]
```